# How to use ant task - native2ascii

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to convert a .txt file which contains accented characters to their equivalent java unicode value. So í is converted to \u00ED .

The filename is called conversion.txt 
Below is how I am trying to use the ant target -

```
<target name="EncodeFile" >
<native2ascii encoding="ISO8859_1" src="C:\Projects\encodingfiles" 
    dest="C:\Projects\encodingfiles"
    includes="C:\Projects\encodingfiles" ext=".txt" />
</target>
```

The ant target runs without error but no conversion takes place.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified a directory for `includes`, from the [`native2ascii` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/native2ascii.html) docs:

> **includes** comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that
>   must be included. All files are included when omitted.

You need to specify a pattern for the files, or an exact name for the file you want to convert.
See [*Directory-based Tasks*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#directorybasedtasks) for the full story.

Another thing to watch out for is if your `src` and `dest` are the same, and you want to convert `.txt` files, specifying `ext=".txt"` will not work.  This is because Ant will determine that, as the source and destination file name are the same, the file is up-to-date with respect to itself as it were, and skip it.
If you need to overwrite the original files, use an alternate `dest` and then copy the converted files back to `src` to overwrite.

(Often running

```
ant -verbose
```

can help to give you more of an idea why Ant has done nothing.)

Comment: In my case ant outputs this: Converting 12 files from <src> to <dest> but I see no change on the created files at all (still accented) Any hints?

Comment: @javy - suggest you post your task xml as a separate question; need more to go on.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, created question as suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435162/native2ascii-task-not-working