# Native2Ascii task not working

Tags: ant, ascii

I'm trying to use the native2ascii ant task but it seems that is not doing anything. Here's my ant task:

```
<target name="-pre-init">
        <native2ascii src="src/com/bluecubs/xinco/messages" dest="src/com/bluecubs/xinco/messages/test" 
        includes="**/_*.properties"/>
        <copy todir="src/com/bluecubs/xinco/messages">
            <fileset dir="src/com/bluecubs/xinco/messages/test"/>
        </copy>
        <delete dir="src/com/bluecubs/xinco/messages/test" />
</target>
```

I did the copy part to see if it was an overwriting issue but the files come out exactly the same.

This is the output I get when running the task:

```
Converting 12 files from Z:\Netbeans\Xinco\2.01.xx\Xinco\src\com\bluecubs\xinco\messages to Z:\Netbeans\Xinco\2.01.xx\Xinco\src\com\bluecubs\xinco\messages\test
Copying 12 files to Z:\Netbeans\Xinco\2.01.xx\Xinco\src\com\bluecubs\xinco\messages
Deleting directory Z:\Netbeans\Xinco\2.01.xx\Xinco\src\com\bluecubs\xinco\messages\test
```

Edit:

Additional information:
OS: Windows 7 (but answer should work on any OD)
File encoding: Western (ISO-8859-1) obtained with this [article](http://developers.sun.com/global/technology/standards/reference/faqs/determining-file-encoding.html).

[Files location](https://xinco.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/xinco/trunk/Xinco/src/com/bluecubs/xinco/messages/)

Any idea?

Comment: Suggest you add some details: what changes are you expecting to see,  what environment you are on (Windows?) and what encoding the properties files use.

Comment: Added the requested details. Is hard to predict the changes I want to see besides making it work.

Comment: Those files you linked to look like they already contain ASCII with escaped Unicode - so the Ant task won't need to change them.  Or have they been converted on your system?  For example, in the .ES file do you have a) `general.version=Versi\u00f3n` or b) `general.version=Versión`?

Comment: Now that you mention it the file on Wordpad shows general.version=Versi\u00f3n but shows general.version=Versión on the NetBeans IDE. That was the whole issue!

Comment: I guess that's good news :)  I'll write up a proper answer when I have a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended being a view issue. Looking the files in a raw editor (i.e. Wordpad) showed that the files were already converted by the task. Viewing them from NetBeans shows them the same.

Answer (score 2):

`native2ascii` converts native characters like `áéí` to escaped unicode sequences. It means that `á` will be `\u00e1`, `é` -> `\u00e9` and `í` -> `\u00ed`. After running `native2ascii` your files will be standard ASCII files which are more portable.

`native2ascii` does not touch the characters which are already in the escaped unicode form. Your properties files are already in escaped unicode form so it does not change anything. For example `_XincoMessages_cz.properties` contains this line:

```
general.accessrights=opr\u00E1vnen\u00ED k pr\u00EDstupu
```

It's escaped unicode. The nonescaped unicode form is this:

```
general.accessrights=oprávnení k prístupu
```

Wordpad vs. Netbans: When you open the properties files with Wordpad it opens it as a simple text file and shows `\u00e1` as `\u00e1`. It does not convert it back to `á`. Netbeans does this conversion and you see the 'á' character. Furthermore, it writes it back to the disk as `\u00e1` (!) when you save the file. To see the raw files use for example a Total or [Double Commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/) which doesn't do any converting. (Note that Netbeans does this conversion just for properties files.)

If you put for example an `á` character to your `_XincoMessages_cz.properties` file it will be changed to `\u00e1` if your run your ant task. Of course now don't use Netbeans for the editing, a simple notepad will do.

Loading properties files in java converts the escaped unicode characters to real unicode characters. An example:

```
final Reader inStream = new FileReader("..../_XincoMessages_cz.properties");
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(inStream);
System.out.println(properties.getProperty("general.accessrights"));
```

It prints:

```
oprávnení k prístupu
```

The ASCII/escaped unicode form in properites files is usually handled well by java applications. Finally, I think your properties files are good in their current format.

Comment: Good answer, but the issue is that there was no problem to start with.